# Как по нажатию на button перейти на сайт?

Tags: android, button, link

Добрый день! Как мне прописать в кнопке `button`, чтобы по нажатию открывался браузер и сайт? Т.е. мне нужно поменять ссылку на сайт, а `button` открывает этот сайт из приложения.

Все как обычно:

```
        View.OnClickListener oclBtnOk = new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                switch (view.getId()) {
                    case R.id.button9:
```

Ну и в case нужно прописать то, что откроет сайт.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Неявный вызов intent, где укажите ссылку *MY_URL* на страницу.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(MY_URL));
startActivity(intent);
```